# What's the point of an Impl block without struct fields in rust?

Tags: rust

I don't really understand why there is the case where one would create an empty struct like this:

`pub struct Foo;`

and then subsequently have this:

```
impl Foo {
...
}
```

It just doesn't make sense to me, why not just create a mod within the crate with a file that has the functions within the impl block above?

Comment: One reason is that it allows for chaining method calls.

Comment: Have you seen this somewhere in the wild?

Comment: Do you have an example? I can think of [`chrono::offset::Utc`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html)... but that has more than just an inherent `impl` block to justify its existence.

Comment: @kmdreko you mean with multiple impl blocks, it's justified?

Comment: The traits that `Utc` implements makes it justified. Traits are used to provide behavior generically and sometimes you don't need to keep any state to do that. All the examples in kaya3's link provide some kind of behavior through their trait implementations.

Comment: Unit structs are also useful to encode e.g. type-coded state machines. In which case the transitions are method calls on the unit structs representing the individual states.